# C++ Set Locale across the entire program

Tags: c++, locale, global

I"m looking for a way to set the locale across the entire program, if that"s even possible.

I set the locale in my main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn"t set the locale to my different classes/methods across the entire program. I"d rather not write this line on top of every method that will print on the screen and creating a C++ locale object and passing it around doesn"t quite feel acceptable.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `setlocale` is already global, for the things it's supposed to affect. What kinds of stuff are those other methods using? As I recall, `setlocale` affects the older "C-like" APIs but doesn't touch stuff like `cout` and C++ streams.

Comment: I have a class which read from a file and cout some of it's content. It's spilling me garbage because some letters have accents. setlocale set in the main, but doesn't seems to affect that second class.

Comment: That's not specific enough to rule out numerous possibilties... You might be using something that setlocale doesn't affect, such as std::fstream. Or the issue might be with cout and the console. Or your file's data might be in an encoding which won't be converted the way you expect. Etc. At this point I think you should either edit this question or post a new one covering the actual problem you're having and post the code of how you're reading the file and sending the data through cout.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The two functions that modify global locale settings are [std::setlocale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) and [std::locale::global](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/global). All future C and C++ I/O and string manipulation will use them, except for the six standard I/O C++ streams, which are constructed before your code runs, so you may have to imbue them individually if so desired:

```
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>
int main()
{
   std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // for C and C++ where synced with stdio
   std::locale::global(std::locale("")); // for C++
   std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
   // cerr, clog, wcout, wcerr, wclog as needed
```

Answer (score 2):

[setlocale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/) used for setting the locale, but its scope if decided by the first parameter (i.e. flag) that we pass. In your case, "LC_ALL".

There are two ways to set the locale. So, as per behavior of the setlocale, if you pass second parameter as "" or NULL, it takes the default from the system enviornment (`LANG`). Code for reference as below:

```
setenv("LANG","en_US.utf8",1);
cout << "GET ENV .... " << getenv("LANG");
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
```

The other way is to use the locale, as below:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.utf8");
```

[Code Illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34035866/4361073)