# How can I give "Japanese/Chinese" data?

Tags: c++

**Context:** Japanese sample data, does not get displayed (cout) as is taken in sample. Why so?

Below is the code:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
wchar_t *pStrAddr = L"日本語";
wcout <<"pStrAddr:: "<< pStrAddr << std::endl;
```

Output is observed as:

```
pStrAddr:: �,�
```

Comment: You could keep the sample-data in some other files with the appropriate encoding and read it in for each test (perhaps via a fixture).

Comment: please revisit the refined query.

Comment: This works for me, are you sure your terminal font has support for these characters? The fact that you're seeing question marks suggests this is the case. Try switching the console font to something with good unicode support.

Comment: yes, the terminal has support for the utf8. Verified as : direct cout of "日本語" works well !

Comment: This works for me，So I'm wondering if you now understand why it's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the code below for answers, it works well now.

> Locale setting Code 1:

```
setenv("LANG","en_US.utf8",1);              //"en_GB.utf8" or "ja_JP.utf8" etc.
cout << "GET ENV .... " << getenv("LANG");
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
```

> Locale setting Code 2:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.utf8");
```

Also I had to use the [wcstombs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/) together with the [setlocale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/). Here goes my revised code that works.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.utf8");
wchar_t *pStrAddr = L"日本語";
wcout <<"pStrAddr:: "<< pStrAddr << std::endl;
cout << "HARDCODED : 日本語" << endl;

char strBuffer[11];                 //char []
int retStrAddr = wcstombs ( strBuffer, pStrAddr, sizeof(strBuffer) );
if (retStrAddr==11)
    strBuffer[11-1]='\0';   //since, not NULL terminated
//to string, as per converter support
std::cout << "multibyte strBuffer: " << strBuffer << '\n';
```

**Output::**

```
pStrAddr:: �,�
HARDCODED : 日本語
multibyte strBuffer: 日本語
```

Comment: Did you get it working with `wcout`? You have utf8 locale, and the values you give to `cout` are utf8, so it is kind of obvious that you can get correct output with that. On the other hand, you are giving utf16 value to `wcout`.

Comment: no @Ville-Valtteri, with the `wcout` I could never see the desired japanese charaters. I tried, setting the terminal encoding with utf8/utf16, but could not get the proper output. However, I am able to see correct output with `wprintf(L"%ls",..)`, with terminal utf-8 encoding state.